# Creating buckets to categorize the values using MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, bucket, mysql-8.0

Hi I am trying to create a buckets for a very large number of rows. I have a maximum value of  `9759721` and a minimum value of `1006909`. I would like to show the results as following:

| distance | bucket | range |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1006909 | 0 | 1000000 - 1009999 |
| 1013525 | 1 | 1010000 - 1019999 |
| 1021948 | 2 | 1020000 - 1029999 |

The table might not be so clear but in general, I would like to break down them by a change of 10000. Creating a new bucket once every `10000` starting from `1000000`.

I tried the following code but it doesn't show the correct output.

```
select distance,floor(distance/10000) as _floor  from data;
```

I got something like:

| distance | bucket |
| --- | --- |
| 1006909 | 100 |
| 1013525 | 101 |
| 1021948 | 102 |
| 1035472 | 103 |
| 1042069 | 104 |
| 9759721 | 975 |

This seems to be correct but I need the bucket to start from 0 and then change based on 10000. And then have a range column as well. The minimum value that I have for distance is 1006909 and so the data doesn't start with 0 but is it possible to still have a bucket column starting from 0 [i.e assigned to minimum distance].

Comment: Your buckets DO start from 0, provided that you have data for distances between 0 and 9999.  If you just want bucket 100 to become bucket 0, just deduct 100 from your current calculation?  If that's not what you mean, please edit your answer with more information?  *(Also, please specify what version of MySQL you're using.  MySQL 8 and MySQL 5.x differ quite significantly.)*

Comment: @MatBailie I just edited the tag, regarding the bucket I have minimum value of 1006909 and so my data doesn't start with 0. But is it not possible to start the bucket from 0 or 1 regardless of where your data is starting ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
  d.distance,
  DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY d._floor) - 1  AS bucket,
  d._floor * 10000                           AS bucket_lower_limit,
  d._floor * 10000 + 10000                   AS bucket_upper_limit
FROM
(
  SELECT
    distance,
    FLOOR(distance / 10000)  AS _floor
  FROM
    data
)
  AS d
```

***NOTE:*** the will give buckets numbered from 0 upwards, but will also remove all gaps *(such that you sample data will have bucket 5 for the last row, not bucket 975)*

Alternatively, if you need to preserve the gaps...

```
SELECT
  d.distance,
  d._floor - MIN(d._floor) OVER ()   AS bucket,
  d._floor * 10000                   AS bucket_lower_limit,
  d._floor * 10000 + 10000           AS bucket_upper_limit
FROM
(
  SELECT
    distance,
    FLOOR(distance / 10000)  AS _floor
  FROM
    data
)
  AS d
```

Comment: hey I have a case such as 1017743 with `upper bucket limit` as `1020000` and bucket number as  1 and for the value 1021948 the lower limit is also `1020000` and has a bucket number 2. Now, what will happen if I have a value that is exactly 1020000 ? Will it go to bucket 1 or 2

Comment: Ranges like these are to be read as ***Inclusive*** for the lower limit and ***Exclusive*** for the upper limit.  Take the case of floating point value, you wouldn't say `from 1 to 1.9` and `from 2 to 2.9` because then `1.99` isn't accounted for *(you can never be precise enough)*.  So, you say `from 1 to 2` and `from 2 to 3`, where `2` goes in to the second bucket.  This `inclusive from, exclusive to` is often shortened to `[1, 2)`, `[2, 3)`.

Answer (score 1):

Just calculate `1006909 div 10000 * 10000 = 1000000` and subtract it from distance. That'll make the buckets start from 0:

```sql
SELECT distance
     , (distance - a) div 10000 AS bucket
     , distance div 10000 * 10000 AS range_from
     , distance div 10000 * 10000 + (10000 - 1) AS range_to
FROM t
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT MIN(distance) div 10000 * 10000 AS a
  FROM t
) AS x
```

[SQL Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=d5d8a82f9c2a58d2f0119867eb269c21)

Comment: Using integer division (`div`) is a fine point, but why use a sub-query to re-scan the data?  Especially when `MIN(x) OVER ()` exists?